# Use case of Android Sync-Adapter

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

From [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/02/new-social-apis-in-android-ics.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+blogspot/hsDu+%28Android+Developers+Blog%29&utm_content=Google+Reader),

> A Contact joins multiple raw contacts into one aggregate. This is what
> the user perceives as a real contact in the People and Phone apps.
>
> A sync adapter synchronizes its raw contacts with its cloud source. It
> can be bundled with a Market application (examples: Skype, Twitter,
> Google+).
>
> While users deal with contacts, sync adapters work with their raw
> contact rows. They own the data inside a raw contact, but by design it
> is left up to Android to properly join raw contact rows with others.

So, now let's say that there is a contact having different raw contact entries one each of Skype, Twitter, etc.

So, my question is that can I use sync adapter to sync contacts as a whole with the cloud storage or are the sync adapters just meant to provide sync functionality to the content providers belonging to the application
like for Twitter app to sync Twitter contacts and for Skype app to sync Skype contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Sync adapters are generally used to work at account level, such that the user uses Google account to sync his contacts from the server to his device, like wise for Facebook and Twitter.

Contacts uses the name, number and other details to aggregate raw contacts from different accounts to a single Contact.

Considering the cloud storage, what you can do is copy all the details even from Twitter, Facebook, Google to your cloud server but not vice versa. Twitter, Facebook have some APIs for developers to use but not Google.